# How do I use Walsh-Hadamard matrices to compute Fourier coefficients of a boolean function?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am reading through the text [*Analysis of Boolean Functions* by Ryan O'Donnell](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amnon/Classes/2016-PRG/Analysis-Of-Boolean-Functions.pdf), and I am struggling with exercise 1.12, which is the following:

> A *Hadamard Matrix* is any $N \times N$ real matrix with $\pm 1$ entries and orthogonal rows. Particular examples are the *Walsh-Hadamard Matrices* $H_N$, inductively defined for $N=2^n$ as follows: $H_1 = [1]$, $$H_{2^{n+1}} = \begin{bmatrix}
> \,H_{2^n} & H_{2^n}\\
> \,H_{2^n} & -H_{2^n}\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   **(a)** Let's index the rows and columns of $H_{2^n}$ by the integers $\{0,1,2,...2^n-1\}$ rather than $[2^n]$. Further, let's identify such an integer $i$ with its binary expansion $(i_0, i_1,...i_{n-1})\in \mathbb{F}_2^n$, where $i_0$ is the least significant bit and $i_{n-1}$ the most. For example, if $n=3$, we identify the index $i=6$ with $(0,1,1)$. Now show that the $(\gamma,x)$ entry of $H_{2^n}$ is $(-1)^{\gamma \cdot x}$.
>
> **(b)** Show that if $f : \mathbb{F}_2^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is represented as a column vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$ (according to the indexing scheme from part (a)) then $$\hat{f} = 2^{-n}H_{2^n} f$$ Here we think of $\hat{f}$ as also being a function $\mathbb{F}_2^n \to \mathbb{R}$, identifying subsets $S \subseteq \{0,1,...n-1\}$ with their indicator vectors.

There are two more parts to the exercise in the textbook, but since I haven't even completed part **(b)**, I'll leave them out of this question.

---

For part **(a)**, I think my solution is correct. I did a proof by induction on $n$, and separated $H_{2^{n+1}}$ into four quadrants to complete the inductive step. Essentially, adding $2^n$ to a coordinate is equivalent to changing the most significant bit from a $0$ to $1$, and the dot product of the $\gamma$ and $x$ coordinates is unchanged by this unless both are increased by $2^n$, which happens only in the bottom right quadrant (which explains the negation in that quadrant).

---

I don't know how to approach part **(b)**.

I know what $\hat{f}$ means according to O'Donnell's definition. Given a boolean function $f$, $\hat{f}(S)$ is the fourier coefficient of $f$ on $S$.

However, I don't understand how to show this computation of the fourier coefficients using the Walsh-Hadamard matrices.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=3,$ for concreteness. As you said, the correspondence is:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|l}
\mathbb{1}(S) & \leftrightarrow & S \\ \hline
(0,0,0) &\leftrightarrow & \{\} \\
(1,0,0) & \leftrightarrow & \{ 1 \}\\
(0,1,0) &\leftrightarrow & \{2\} \\
(1,1,0) & \leftrightarrow & \{ 1,2 \}\\
(0,0,1) &\leftrightarrow & \{3 \} \\
(1,0,1) & \leftrightarrow & \{ 1,3 \}\\
(0,1,1) &\leftrightarrow & \{2,3\} \\
(1,1,1) & \leftrightarrow & \{ 1,2,3 \}\\
\end{array}
$$
and by observing the entries of the matrix are $(-1)^{\gamma\cdot x}$
we obtain
$$\hat{f}(S)=2^{-n}\sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_2^n} (-1)^{ \mathbb{1}(S) \cdot x}=2^{-n}H_{2^n} f,$$
where $\mathbb{1}(S)$ denotes the indicator vector of $S.$

Comment: Thank you! I understand your table on the correspondence between subsets $S$ and their indicator vectors $1(S)$. However, I don't understand either of the equalities you wrote below ...

Comment: I see in the textbook there is an expression of the fourier coefficient of $f$ on $S$ in terms of an inner product of $f$ and $\chi_S$, is this what you're using? $$\hat{f}(S) = \langle f, \chi_S \rangle$$

Comment: I think I understand it (mostly) now? Regardless, thank you again for the help :)